# DependencyInjection Error - migration Symfony2 to Symfony3 - The argument "x" doesn't exist

Tags: symfony

I am performing migration from Symfony 2.7 to Symfony 3+. Multiple components and dependencies have been updated.

I managed to fix configurations issues  regarding firewall setup, forms and some extenstions (services).

Sorting one problem introduced me to another. 
Now each time I run `php bin/console` I get an error:

```
[Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Exception\OutOfBoundsException]
  The argument "3" doesn't exist.
```

I have tried to run it with -v or -vvv option and I only got:

```
Exception trace:
 () at /xx/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/Definition.php:242
 Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Definition->getArgument() at /xx/vendor/sonata-project/core-bundle/DependencyInjection/Compiler/FormFactoryCompilerPass.php:48
 Sonata\CoreBundle\DependencyInjection\Compiler\FormFactoryCompilerPass->process() at /xx/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/Compiler/Compiler.php:139
 Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Compiler\Compiler->compile() at /xx/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/ContainerBuilder.php:710
 Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder->compile() at /xx/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/Kernel.php:515
 Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel->initializeContainer() at /xx/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/Kernel.php:117
 Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel->boot() at /xx/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Console/Application.php:68
 Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Console\Application->doRun() at /xx/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php:121
 Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run() at /xx/bin/console:28
```

It looks like the issue with container compliation: 
http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dependency_injection/compilation.html

Some old setup passed validation but it is not consumed properly by DependencyInjection Compiler.

I have fallowing questions:

- How I can debug it?
- What can cause problem like this?
- How to fix it?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you just typing in 'php bin/console' or is there more you are typing on the command line?

Comment: to me it looks like your Sonata Core Bundle which you integrate is missing a third injection argument. and as always - did you clear your cache?

Comment: @pogeybait - i was trying different commands, error is always the same

Comment: @LBA - of course I did :-) fresh cache and on fresh vendors... I will try another go today

Comment: I think I need to debug whole configuration step by step adding components...

Comment: Please show the result of `composer show sonata-project/*`

Comment: @Mawcel  - command is not working for me but I have 3 modules from sonata project in composer file:        
"sonata-project/admin-bundle": "3.13.*",
"sonata-project/doctrine-orm-admin-bundle": "dev-master",
"sonata-project/core-bundle": "^3.1",